# How to determine function or curve fit unknown function with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwhEMUIYGyTbjBPcUVwQVEtaW8/view?usp=sharing) with 4 X values and one common Y value for all X. Y is a function of X (observed from graphs), but the function value is unknown, which implies, Y = f1(X1), Y = f2(X2), Y = f3(X3) and Y = f4(X4). I am trying to determine the function f1, f2, f3 and f4 with Python. Variation of Y with X is shown in figure.

[image]

**MWE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = np.genfromtxt('unknown_function.dat', delimiter = '\t', skiprows = 1)
y = data[:, 0]
x1 = data[:, 1]
x2 = data[:, 2]
x3 = data[:, 3]
x4 = data[:, 4]


fig = plt.figure()
fig.clf()
plot = plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(x1, y, color = 'k')
plt.plot(x2, y, color = 'r')
plt.plot(x3, y, color = 'b')
plt.plot(x4, y, color = 'g')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

Are there any methods to determine this unknown function with Python?

Answer (score 3):

The data in each column appear to be well-represented by the function f(x) = a0 + a1/x + a2/x^2 + a3/x^3.  The scipy.optimize package (good example at http://www2.mpia-hd.mpg.de/~robitaille/PY4SCI_SS_2014/_static/15.%20Fitting%20models%20to%20data.html) can do the function fitting relatively easily and return the fitted parameters.  I've added the relevant code to your MWE below for the 'x1' column of data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = np.genfromtxt('unknown_function.dat', delimiter = '\t', skiprows = 1)
y = data[:, 0]
x1 = data[:, 1]
x2 = data[:, 2]
x3 = data[:, 3]
x4 = data[:, 4]

def f1(x, a0, a1, a2, a3):
    return a0 + a1/x + a2/x**2 + a3/x**3

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f1, x1, y)
print "Function fit to x1 data column: a0 + a1/x + a2/x**2 + a3/x**3"
print "Parameters from least-squares fit:"
print "a0 =", popt[0], "+/-", pcov[0,0]**0.5
print "a1 =", popt[1], "+/-", pcov[1,1]**0.5
print "a2 =", popt[2], "+/-", pcov[2,2]**0.5
print "a3 =", popt[3], "+/-", pcov[3,3]**0.5

fig = plt.figure()
fig.clf()
plot = plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(x1, y, color = 'k')
xfine = np.linspace(min(x1), max(x1), 100)
plt.plot(xfine, f1(xfine, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3]), 'r-')
plt.plot(x2, y, color = 'r')
plt.plot(x3, y, color = 'b')
plt.plot(x4, y, color = 'g')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Actually what you just described is the basis for a linear model. That could be fit also using scikit-learn or statsmodels.

Answer (score 1):

@davmat gave an excellent solution. This is a scikit-learn based version of his solution using a linear model with his basis functions.

Load the data using Pandas

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('unknown_function.dat', delimiter='\t')from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

Define a function to fit the data using a linear model with @davmat's basis.

```
def fit_function(x,y):
    linmodel = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
    x_vectors = np.column_stack([x**-i for i in range(4)])
    linmodel.fit(x_vectors, y)
    return linmodel.coef_

coef1 = fit_function(df['X1'], df['Y'])
coef2 = fit_function(df['X2'], df['Y'])
coef3 = fit_function(df['X3'], df['Y'])
coef4 = fit_function(df['X4'], df['Y'])
```

Evaluate function with each set of fitted coefficients.

```
def f1(x, coefs):
    return coefs[0] + coefs[1]/x + coefs[2]/x**2 + coefs[3]/x**3


%matplotlib inline
df['y1hat'] = df['X1'].apply(lambda x: f1(x,coef1))
df['y2hat'] = df['X2'].apply(lambda x: f1(x,coef2))
df['y3hat'] = df['X3'].apply(lambda x: f1(x,coef3))
df['y4hat'] = df['X4'].apply(lambda x: f1(x,coef3))
```

Plot the results

```
df.plot(x='X1', y=['Y','y1hat'])
df.plot(x='X2', y=['Y','y2hat'])
df.plot(x='X3', y=['Y','y3hat'])
df.plot(x='X4', y=['Y','y4hat'])
```

[image: y1hat vs y]
[image: y2hat vs y]
[image: y3hat vs y]
[image: y4hat vs y]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a polynomial regression.

```
Y = F(x) = c0 + c1 x + c2 x^2 + c3 ×^3 +  ...... + cn x^n
```

the idea is to choose the value of n and to compute the coefficients c0, c1, ...cn

But keep in mind that this is only an approximation